# Gauss Seidel convergence in Scilab

Tags: scilab

```
A=[4 1;4 6 ]
b=[6:-8]
x=zeros(2,1]
MaxIter=100
Iter=0
P=0
while (P==0)
for i=1:1m
 s=0
  for j=1:1:m
    if i~=j then
      s=s+A(i,j)*x(j);
    end
  end
x(i)=(b(i)-s)/A(i,i));
end 
Iter=Iter+1
printf("\n\n\t%d",Iter")
printf("\t    %f",x)
end
mprintf ("\n\nThe approximate solutions are: %.3f",x)
```

What should I put on my convergence criterion before Iter+Iter+1 to stop the while loop at the tolerance error 0.0001 if I subtract the latest values of approximation to the previous approximations

Comment: The next time you post in SO please make sure that your program is at least valid w.r.t. Scilab syntax. You have a plenty of syntax errors in your program. For example `x=zeros(2,1]` (closing bracket instead of parenthesis).

Comment: The rule if you find the answer usefull is to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

The most used criterion measures the norm of the difference between successive iterates, hence, you could just save the previous x at the begining of your while loop and update it after the new x is computed:

```
A=[4 1;4 6]
b=[6;-8]
m=2;
x=zeros(m,1)
MaxIter=100
for Iter = 0:MaxIter
    prev_x = x;
    for i=1:m
        s=0;
        for j=1:m
            if i~=j then
                s=s+A(i,j)*x(j);
            end
        end
        x(i)=(b(i)-s)/A(i,i);
    end 
    mprintf("\n\n\t%d",Iter)
    mprintf("\t    %f",x)
    if norm(x-prev_x) < 0.0001
        break
    end
    prev_x = x;
end
mprintf ("\n\nThe approximate solutions are:");
mprintf("\t    %f",x)
```